# RO turing machine with finite memory

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, reductions, computation-models

Consider the following:

A *weak* TM is a TM with finite tape in size $k$ which can only **read** its input values. note: the tape size does not include the input length.

I need to determine whether if the *weak* model is equivalent to a regular TM, or to explain why not and to show the equivalence to any other computational model.

I'm quiet confident that the weak TM is equivalent to a DFA with $\gamma^k\cdot q\cdot (n+k)$ states where $|\Gamma| = \gamma$, $|Q| = q$ and $|w| = n$.

My intuition is that there are at most $\gamma^k$ strings that the machine can write, there are $q$ states and the head can be stationed at one of the $n+k$ slots on the tape.

I'm having a hard time to prove it though, Anyone can shed some light?

Comment: Does $k$ scale with the input size? Or is it constant for every machine (as, e.g., its number of states)?

Comment: Also, any TM is equivalent to a DFA if the input size is fixed; this is trivial. The problem is that, for most machines, the respective DFAs are nonuniform across the input space.

Comment: If you can't prove it, maybe try to refute your guess?  Can the weak TM recognize palindromes of size $k$? What about the DFA?  (and what is $w$ in its def?)

Comment: $w$ would be the input word.